# Alertify in Laravel in hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, alertifyjs

they could help me, I have a project in Laravel, everything works correctly in Localhost, but now that it is in the service the alertify do not work and do not let the view return, if I delete the alertify everything works fine (the sql lines, the boostrap, the routes, everything works fine without the alertify)

this is one of the functions with Alertify but they do not work as explained above:

```
public function create(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = new User($request->all());
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
    $user->save();

    alertify()->success('USER ' . $user->name . ' CREATED.')
    ->position('bottom right')
    ->delay(6000);
    return redirect()->route('users_path');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added alertify library

```
composer require odannyc/laravel-alertify
```

or

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alertifyjs/alertify.js/v1.0.10/dist/js/alertify.js"></script>
```

and try with

```
alertify()->success('USER WAS CREATED.')->delay(6000)->position('bottom right');
```

If above line works then check `$user->name` this has data (`dd($user->name)`)